# MongoDB aggregation, find number of distinct values in documents' arrays

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Reading [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/), I see you can get the number of elements in document arrays. For example given the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "description" : "product 1", colors: [ "blue", "black", "red" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "description" : "product 2", colors: [ "purple" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "XYZ1", "description" : "product 3", colors: [ ] }
```

and the following query:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([{$project: {item: 1, numberOfColors: { $size: "$colors" }}}])
```

We would get the number of elements in each document's `colors` array:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "numberOfColors" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "numberOfColors" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "XYZ1", "numberOfColors" : 0 }
```

I've not been able to figure out if and how you could sum up all the colors in all the documents directly from a query, ie:

```
{ "totalColors": 4 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the count of all colors in all docs:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([ 
  { $unwind: '$colors' } , // expands nested array so we have one doc per each array value 
  { $group: {_id: null, allColors: {$addToSet: "$colors"} } }  , // find all colors
  { $project: { totalColors: {$size: "$allColors"}}} // find count of all colors
 ])
```

Answer (score 2):

Infinitely better is is to simply [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/):

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
  { "$group": { "_id": null, "totalColors": { "$sum": { "$size": "$colors" } } }
])
```

If you wanted "distinct in each document" then you would instead:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "totalColors": {
      "$sum": {
        "$size": { "$setUnion": [ [], "$colors" ] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Where [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) takes values likes `["purple","blue","purple"]` and makes it into `["purple","blue"]` as a "set" with "distinct items".

And if you really want "distinct across documents" then **don't** accumulate the "distinct" into a single document. That causes performance issues and simply does not scale to large data sets, and can possibly break the 16MB BSON Limit. Instead accumulate naturally via the key:

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$colors" },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$colors" } },
  { "$group": { "_id": null, "totalColors": { "$sum": 1 } } }
])
```

Where you only use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) because you want "distinct" values from the array as combined with other documents. Generally [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) should be avoided unless the value contained in the array is being accessed in the "grouping key" `_id` of [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). Where it is not, it is better to treat arrays using other operators instead, since `$unwind` creates a "copy" of the whole document per array element.

And of course there was also nothing wrong with simply using [`.distinct()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) here, which will return the "distinct" values "as an array", for which you can just test the [`Array.length()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) on in code:

```
var totalSize = db.inventory.distinct("colors").length;
```

Which for the simple operation you are asking, would be the overall **fastest** approach for a simple "count of distinct elements". Of course the limitation remains that the result cannot exceed the 16MB BSON limit as a payload. Which is where you defer to `.aggregate()` instead.